# Loading results via AJAX continously as user types in an input field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve an Ajax search/autocomplete as user types in. Here is my code:

```
$('#productSearch').live('keyup',function(){
    var searchterm = encodeURIComponent($('#productSearch').val());
    $('.ajax-search-results').load('/ajax/search.php?type=product&s=' + searchterm);

});
```

The problem is that results are not consistent with the input value, I have no idea why, but when I type too fast (too fast for handling the .load() maybe?) the results at end are not consistent (not what I expect) if i type in slowly, it works perfectly.

Can someone tell me how can I come over this situation?

- I thought about disabling function until the load is done, but that would mean also that i will lose what the user has typed until the operation is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually fixed with a small timeout so as to not stack requests on top of each other and do ajax for every key when the user types fast, and by aborting the previous calls if doing regular $.ajax calls (not so easy to `abort()` XHR with load()):

```
var timer;

$(document).on('keyup', '#productSearch',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var searchterm = encodeURIComponent($('#productSearch').val());
        $('.ajax-search-results').load('/ajax/search.php?type=product&s=' + searchterm);
    }, 300);
});
```